# How can I see when a Widget rebuilds?

Tags: flutter, dart

[Code source](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertimertutorial?id=actions)

Is there any trick to know that a widget has been rebuilt?

As a demonstration, i.e. if we randomly colored the widgets on every rebuild, it would look like this:

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I'm learning BloC, so I want see widget rebuild status visually to mark sure my logic is correct.

Answer (score 9):

Flutter actually has built-in functionality for **exactly** what you are trying to achieve in the [DevTools inspector](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector):

[image: Demonstration]

This is called the **Repaint Rainbow** and it can be enabled in Android Studio, i.e. IntelliJ, as demonstrated above or directly in Dart DevTools:

[image: DevTools screenshot]

### Repaint Rainbow

> Shows rotating colors on layers when repainting.

<sup>From [the linked article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector)</sup>

### Notes

- There can be many reasons for repaints and seeing a widget rebuild does not inherently mean that you triggered the rebuild as it can also come from somewhere else in the tree.
- You cannot know if a widget has been rebuilt in code because that is against how the framework works - you can obviously catch any build or paint calls by integrating that into your `build` or `paint` function, but you should really not do that because *builds and paints **should be idempotent***.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I don't know why I cannot expect results (like a gif) in [flutter_timer](https://github.com/felangel/Bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_timer), maybe because not using `StatefulWidget`?

Comment: @CHWing I am afraid to say that I do not understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 6):

If you use android studio you can open Flutter Performance and checked Track widgets rebuild in Widget rebuild stats[image]

Comment: My Android Studio's Flutter Performance doesn't show the file name in the location it only shows the Line number . Any Fixes ?Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is an important tool and it is only available through IntelliJ IDE at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Every time the widgets are rebuild ,the `build()` is called So You can write a `print()` in your `build()` and track when the widgets are getting rebuilt

Answer (score 0):

You can't know it, and should not build a word around to obtain that value yourself either.

This is anti pattern, as the number of times a widget rebuilt should **never** have an impact on the output.

Comment: I agree. You might also want to check my answer regarding the random colors on rebuild :)

Comment: Isn't it affecting performance? I faced kind of the same problem - the ListView items are repainted each time one of the items is changed. And I can't really trace where it comes from which might be useful to understand how to prevent it.